# R: used "write.csv" inside a loop but R won't read it back in

Tags: r, loops, csv, driver, dataframe

I have a short loop I used to create several .csv files.  The loop works and the files are created correctly, and I can open them in Microsoft Excel.  Everything looks great.  But when I try to read these files back into R in another script, R doesn't recognize them.

Do you need to turn off some sort of driver inside the loop as you would if you were creating several png files?

Here is the loop (works). For reference, dtlm is a large dataframe with several columns including "diag", "county" and "date" and "Freq".

```
single = c("492", "493", "427", "428", "786")
for (q in 1:length(single))  {
    xx = xtabs(~date+county, data=dtlm, subset = dtlm$diag == single[q])
    xy=as.data.frame(xx)
    write.csv(xy, paste(single[q], ".csv", sep=""))
}
```

Now here is an example of a command that R can't recognize the file with:

```
dt <- read.csv("C:/Users/myname/Desktop/FreqTables/492.csv")
```

So weird! I have also tried read.table and that didn't work either, and I didn't find anything helpful in ?read.csv.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "R can't recognize the file with"? What is the result when you try to read it?

Comment: Also, why are you working in the current directory for the write, but then using a full path for the read? I'd guess that's the cause so choose one or the other for both and see if it makes a difference. Windows 7 and Vista can be cryptic with paths

Comment: I'm using the full file path because I had moved the files into a folder to sort them for organization purposes. The error is  in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/mtinling/Desktop/FreqTables/493.csv': No such file or directory
>

Comment: Well you must have buggered it up somehow, what do you see with getwd() when you are writing them? Just remove the ambiguity between relative and absolute path here and the problem will no doubt disappear. Add this detail into the question to improve it.

Comment: If it is not a typo issue, maybe you have moved your files to a directory you current Windows/R session does not have access to. You could try and run `file.access`, `file.info`, and `list.files` on your "C:/Users/mtinling/Desktop/FreqTables" directory.

Comment: Hey all,  so I never figured out what the issue was- I ended up just going back and rerunning the loop.  R reads them in now- maybe it was the file path issue some of you suggested.  Thanks for all your tips- I am learning to problem solve more and more every day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I normally do,

```
## store the path in some object, here 'dir'
dir <- "[path to the folder where you have your data]"

## then pick up the file names from the 'dir,' change the filter as needed
fnames <- list.files(path = dir, pattern = ".csv")

## read the data into a list
dfn = list()
for (string in fnames){
dfn[[string]]=read.csv(paste(dir,string,sep = ""))
}
```

You can probably do it in fewer lines, but this works for me.

If you like to merge the files together you can use something like this, note that I bring in the file name from the csv files

```
## remove the .csv suffix
names(dfn) <- strsplit(names(dfn),".csv")

## merging the data frames together (traditional)
DF <- dfn[[1]]
for ( .df in dfn) {
DF <-merge(DF, .df, by.x="ID", by.y="ID", all.x=T,
           suffixes=paste(":", names(dfn), sep = ""))
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Best,
Eric